# UndefVarError st not defined. I have no variable called st in my code

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, julia

Homework question to return path tupples of path of least weight in a matrice. However the code gives me an error as: UndefVarError st not defined?

I have tried running the program without the for loops, and returning just s, and that works.

```
function backtrack(pathweights)
    s = size(pathweights)[1]
    bestpath = []
    a = argmin(pathweights[:, s])
    push!(bestpath, (size(pathweights)[1]-1,a))

    for j = size(pathweights)[1]:-1:1
        b = argmin(pathweights[:, j])
        for i = 1: size(pathweights)
            if isdefined[pathweights[b+1,j-1]] && 
            isdefined[pathweights[b-1,j-1]]
                push!(bestpath, (min(pathweights[b, j-1], 
                pathweights[b-1,j-1], pathweights[b+1, j-1]), j))
            else if isempty[pathweights[a+1,j-1]]
                push!(bestpath, (min(pathweights[b-1, j- 
                1],pathweights[b, j-1]), j))
            else
                push!(bestpath, (min(pathweights[b, j-1], 
                pathweights[b+1,j-1]), j))
            end
        end
    end
    return bestpath
 end
```

Iinput: 
pathweights = [3  6  8  6  3
              10 9  11 10 6
              13 19 13 7  12
              23 17 10 8  9
              23 11 15 11 17]
Expected output: 
bestpath = [(5,2), (4,3), (3,4), (2,5), (1,5)]

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place to solve for your homework questions for you (at least not in that way). Carefully check and read the error messages (e.g. in which line is the error occuring?) and narrow down the problem. If some behaviour is still unclear to you try to come up with a _minimal_ example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using Juno and are trying to evaluate a file which contains an error.

This bug was reported [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/ann-juno-0-11/29644/6?u=pfitzseb) and fixed by this [commit](https://github.com/JunoLab/Atom.jl/commit/e741e96a960d0c21a8370a1f877dac5a154302dc), so please update to Atom.jl 0.11.1 (with `using Pkg; Pkg.update()` and try again.